# Encoding Problem with Facebook Send Button

Tags: facebook, html, encoding

Part of the title of the page is **Satılık Audi A3**, when clicking send button it seems that there is encoding problem (see picture below). I'm using html 5 and I have the following charset;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

instead